# Exploding two columns in pandas: ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to explode two columns as follows

```
df2=df[['Name','Surname','Properties','Score']].copy()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.set_index('Name').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

but I have got the error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

My dataset looks like

```
Name       Surname     Properties         Score
A.          McLarry    ['prop1','prop2']  [1,2]
G.          Livingstone []                []
S.          Silver     ['prop5','prop3', 'prop2']   [2,55,2]
...
```

I would like to explode both Properties and Score. If you can tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be great!

Comment: Try `df_out = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pd.Series.explode` as an apply function, after setting ALL the other columns as index. Post that you can `reset_index` to get the columns back. -

```
df.set_index(['Name','Surname']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```